# how to run windows forms app or cmd.exe in NETWORK SERVICE

Tags: .net, impersonation

1. how to run windows forms app or cmd.exe in ASP.NET? (using the NETWORK SERVICE identity)
   I've tried to create a process running a winform program, but nothing happens. 
   I'm using .net 4.0 and windows server 2008 standard, IIS 7.
   I do so for testing impersonation
2. is there any difference on coding impersonation in a winform app and web app?
   I think it should be the same